# Spring Security Bad Credentials Error for Password

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, credentials

I am using spring authentication. I have hit a problem when attempting to use the following password.

```
!"£$%^&*()_+{}:@~|<>?A1
```

The error gives 'Bad credentials'. After doing some debugging I notice in the method 'additionalAuthenticationChecks' of the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` class that

```
String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
```

evaluates to my input password but with a `Â` character before the `£` like so `Â£`

It looks to be the `£` character causing issues.

Any ideas. Let me know if you require me to paste any configuration e.t.c

Comment: This looks like a problem of charset between browser and server. You could ensure you declare a utf-8 charset for the form and control what the browser send with a tool like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org).

Comment: This looks like an encoding issue. Have you used the same charset everywhere (DB, server, client)?

Comment: @SergeBallesta - I have the encoding of the page set to UTF-8 

`<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`

The server I am using withing spring IDE is set to UTF-8 in web.xml and server.xml

Comment: I have additionally attempted to set the content type on the viewResolver